# Creating Modeless Dialog-box from Document Class in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have no problem to create a modal dialog-box from my document class. Just add the following to Document class:

```
CDialog dlg;

dlg.DoModal();
```

But when I want to do the same thing for a Modeless dialog-box it does not work:

```
CDialog * pDialog;  
pDialog = new CDialog();
pDialog->Create(IDD_DIALOG, this);
```

The error I get is :
`error C2664: 'BOOL CDialog::Create(LPCTSTR,CWnd *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'LPCTSTR'`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the 'this' argument should be a CWnd* and you are a CDocument* - try parenting it to the desktop by passing NULL instead of 'this' as the second argument or parent to the mainframe by passing AfxGetMainWnd().

Comment: Did You got any answer? Same problem here!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is

```
pDialog->Create(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), this);
```

Comment: According to the [documentation for `CDialog::Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd(v=vs.80).aspx) it should take an integer parameter directly.